# creating csv file by datatable plugin

Tags: php, csv, datatable

I have a list and by making use of datatable plugin I sort them clearly. Before that by php coding only I make the sorted list. And according to the current list, I can export to csv file.My code was like:

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');



  // create a file pointer connected to the output stream
    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

$rows = mysql_query(base64_decode($_REQUEST['qur']));
        $number = mysql_num_rows($rows);
        if($number > 0){

            fputcsv($output, array('Name','Username','Email','Age','Location','Contact','Privilege','JoiningDate','Status'));

            // loop over the rows, outputting them
            $blankArray = array();
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) {
                $name = $row['admin_name'];
                $username = $row['username'];
                $email = $row['email'];
                $age = $row['age'];
                $location = $row['location'];
                $cont = $row['contact_no'];
                $priv = get_role_name_by_id($row['role']);
                $doj = substr($row['creation_date'],0,10);
                $status = ($row['status'] == '1')?"enable":"disable";
                $blankArray['Name'] = $name;
                $blankArray['Username'] = $username;
                $blankArray['Email'] = $email;
                $blankArray['Age'] = $age;
                $blankArray['Location'] = $location;
                $blankArray['Contact'] = $cont;
                $blankArray['Privilege'] = $priv;
                $blankArray['JoiningDate'] = $doj;
                $blankArray['Status'] = $status;

                fputcsv($output, $blankArray);

            }
        }else{
            fputcsv($output, array('No Record Found'));
        }
```

And from the page I was using the following piece of code:

```
<a href="export.php?report=user&qur=<?php echo base64_encode($search_sql); ?>"><button>Export to CSV</button></a>
```

Now As I change the sorting option in datatable plugin,and I use the following code :

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
                                "bProcessing": true,
                                "bServerSide": true,
                                "sAjaxSource": "datatabledb.php",
                                "bJQueryUI": true,
                                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                                //"sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                                "oTableTools": {
                                    "aButtons": [
                                        {
                                            "sExtends": "copy",
                                            "sButtonText": "Copy to clipboard"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "sExtends": "csv",
                                            "sButtonText": "Save to CSV"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "sExtends": "xls",
                                            "sButtonText": "Save for Excel"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }                       
                            } );
```

But still it is not showing the button also. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the TableTools that does what you need.

See this [Link!](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/TableTools/index.html) for an example and see this link for the [documentation!](http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/)

Comment: I use that also. But not getting expected result

Comment: But what exactly are you doing? You have a PHP script to provide dataTables with the desired contents, and you need your table to sort, paginate, etc by constantly using that file as the data source? And additionally to that you need to export the table contents to CSV?

Comment: Ya I succeed. actually I did not put the swf folder.By the way, thanks a lot

Comment: But after solving the above issue, I am fetching another issue. I have some search fields based upon name, age range, category drop down etc etc. As per the search parameter, the results will be displayed, but not getting. Please tell how to solve.

Comment: The best way to obtain help concerning a new problem, is to place a new question with the relevant code, only then we are able to help you! Dealing with other problems on this question will lead to a chatty situation, and will probably get your question closed!